# Not able to inspect an element inside a frame in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, frameset

I have a link to be clicked (Expand All) which is inside a frame

I tried switching to the frame first and then the element but am getting exception **"unable to locate element"**.

I have tried locating the element using CSS selector, Xpath, link text but still helpless.

I tried the webdriver wait also but still not able to go through.

My code:

```py
def buttonclickxpath(xpath):
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
def waitforobjectbyxpath(xpath):
return webdriverwait(driver, 10).until (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Xpath,XPATH)))
driver.get('url')
name=driver.find_element_by_name('UserName')
name.send_keys(username)
pwd=driver.find_element_by_name('Password')
pwd.send_keys(password)
buttonclickxpath('/html/body/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/button')
print("Logged in")
time.sleep(5)
oframe = waitforobjectbyXpath('/html/frameset/frame[1]')
print('frame found')
driver.switch_to.frame(oframe)
print('frame found')
time.sleep(5)
expand=waitforobjectbyXpath('/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')
expand.click
```

Frame in which the element (expand)is located

```html
<frame src="/administrator/servlet/tibco_administrator?c.fid=com_tibco_wfc_DefaultFrame_225251420&amp;fdc=3" name="com_tibco_wfc_DefaultFrame_225251420" marginheight="10" marginwidth="10" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1">
```

HTML code when I inspect my element

```html
<a href="#" name="^Expand_All" class="HyperlinkButton" onclick="showProgressMeter();submitCommand(event,'com_tibco_wfc_HyperlinkButton_999262320', 'com_tibco_wfc_DefaultFrame_225251420', false, false, 'null', '', '', false);;return false;">Expand All</a>
```

I even inspecting the element using `driver.find_element_by_name` as only name and class is available in the HTML code.

Cannot inspect with the class name as my element (expand) doesn't exists there.